# Verifying that a required answer has a response before submission

Tags: javascript, html

I am using the Amazon Mechanical Turk template to create a survey (HIT) and would like to have the survey questions required. I have three groups of radio buttons within the survey template that I would like to have all filled out before the form is submitted. I need help with the validation syntax.

Here's one group of my radio buttons:

```
<div class="radio">
    <label><strong><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" /></strong>Yes</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="2" />No</label>
</div>

<div class="radio">
    <label><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="3" />Not sure</label>
</div>
```

I found the code below on stack overflow but I am struggling with the syntax on how to make use of it in regards to my specific radio buttons above. Can someone please help with the syntax to validate that a selection has been made via the radio buttons before submission?

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('submitButton').setAttribute('onclick', 'return validateForm()');
    }

    function validateForm() {
        if (validate) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want you can add `required` to the input tag

**before**

```
<input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" />
```

**after**

```
<strong><input name="ABCD Test" type="radio" value="1" required/>
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/5mmag01c/

Answer (score 0):

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mkxat4db/

```
(function () {
    document.getElementById('submitButton').onclick = validateForm;
    function validateForm() {
       var radios = document.querySelectorAll("input:checked");
        if (radios.length === 0) {
            alert("select one please");
            return false;
        }
        else {
            return true;
        }       
    }
})();
```